# Joining three table together using an SQL statement to grab data from each table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

In my database, I have 3 tables.

Jokes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Category:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And finally, Comments:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I need to join all three tables together to get the category name of a joke, the joke itself, and the unique comments correlating to that specific joke_id.

For the moment I can only join two tables where the joke_id = 1. This will return the comments for that joke.

This function is stored in my read controller, with the name of Joke:

```
public function joke($joke_id = FALSE)
{
    if ($joke_id === FALSE) redirect('main'); //go to default controller

    $data['results'] = $this->comments_m->getComments($joke_id, $this->uri->segment(2));

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('content/read', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');

}
```

The model (comments_m) has a function called getComments which grabs the comments correlating to joke_id = 1:

```
//gets the comments
function getComments (){

    //joke id should grab the id of the joke which was commented on
    $joke_id = 1;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT jokes.*, comments.* FROM jokes LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON jokes.joke_id = comments.joke_id WHERE jokes.joke_id = '$joke_id'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

I need a SQL query in the getComments function which grabs the category name, the joke, the joke_id, comment and comment_id. How can I alter my query to return the information that I nee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT jokes.*,category.*,comments.* from jokes
 INNER JOIN category ON jokes.category_id=category.category_id
 INNER JOIN comments ON jokes.joke_id=comments.joke_id
 where jokes.joke_id = '$joke_id';
```

Comment: @user3898892 don't forget the accept the correct answer